# adding fitted values from lmer to the dataset

Tags: r, lme4

I use `lmer` to fit my model, but also need to add a column with fitted values to the initial dataset.
I assume that my data has some missing values, so it does not work:

```
mlm1 <-lmer(as.formula(paste("SCALE_SCORE_0", paste(predictors1, collapse="+"), sep="~")),data=data_similar_school, REML=TRUE)

data_similar_school$fitted<-fitted(mlm1)
```

Gives

```
Error:
! Assigned data `fitted(mlm1)` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 75640 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 74844 rows.
```

When i just look at fitted - it does not show me any id to match to use `left_join`

How can I fix this?

```
structure(list(PV1.Dim1 = c(0.981394716520856, 0.341980409147505, 
-0.521270085484948, 0.97311736959707, -0.546822408520793, -0.94451585841879, 
-1.12442015156344, -0.212030727461711, 0.510201092377239, -1.61758887197742, 
0.960044294795618, 1.0808224166442, 1.81324290458999, 2.93944976463897, 
1.55028346629664, 0.239714631887717, 1.8833815579897, 1.01911941187452, 
2.05179728213341, -0.338893180852708), PV1_school = c(-0.30369920227854, 
0.401255701674977, -0.628650879209856, -0.54159146533509, -0.580241012883394, 
0.317952081717246, -0.632422818856145, -0.112778723746489, -0.9695016577952, 
0.0125014069789618, 0.89437802969317, -0.609837809102642, -0.609837809102642, 
0.734933868917248, -0.481812149393699, 0.52042087568074, -1.04493824155896, 
-0.568286399189493, -0.192271961357116, -0.270710065980736), 
    ATSI_FLAG1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ATSI_FLAG_per_school = c(0.0373134328358209, 
    0.0072992700729927, 0.025974025974026, 0.0459770114942529, 
    0, 0.00836820083682008, 0, 0, 0.131428571428571, 0.0181818181818182, 
    0.00476190476190476, 0.211267605633803, 0.211267605633803, 
    0.00374531835205993, 0.0454545454545455, 0, 0.00909090909090909, 
    0.00602409638554217, 0.0150375939849624, 0.0104712041884817
    ), mother_l1_recode = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("1201", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "9", "not_provided"), class = "factor"), VCAA_SCHOOL_CD = c("42851", 
    "38828", "39023", "39101", "38548", "29876", "11676", "41339", 
    "29145", "38424", "38707", "38814", "38814", "38846", "39072", 
    "11264", "42219", "39158", "11517", "29431"), SCALE_SCORE_0 = c(416.3, 
    395.8, 305, 317.8, 337.5, 479.4, 394.8, 447, 330.1, 374.9, 
    544.7, 416.3, 364.2, 385.4, 330.1, 580.6, 276.9, 464.1, 250.4, 
    341.8)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a portion of  the data using `dput(head(data_similar_school, 20))`

Comment: what is `predictors1` ? please give a fully reproducible code : )

Comment: You should be able to use something like: `data_similar_school$fitted[!is.na(data_similar_school$SCALE_SCORE_0)]<- fitted(mlm1)`

Comment: Also, I don't see any random effects in your model.

Comment: Edward, for this specific one - i don't report random effects

Answer (score 0):

If you use the optional argument `na.action = na.exclude` everything should work OK, e.g.

```r
library(lme4)
ss <- sleepstudy
ss$Days[c(1,2,8)] <- NA
nrow(ss)  ## 180
```

### default (na.action = na.omit)

```r
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), ss)
length(fitted(m1))  ## 177
```

### with na.action  = na.exclude

```r
m2 <- update(m1, na.action = na.exclude)
length(fitted(m2))  ## 180
```

FWIW it would be cleaner to write your model as

```r
ff <- reformulate(predictors1, response = "SCALE_SCORE_0")
mlm1 <- lmer(ff, data=data_similar_school, REML=TRUE, na.action = na.exclude)
```

You could also use `broom.mixed::augment()` (although it warns that you need to specify the optional `data=` argument if you use `na.exclude`).